# почему переменная не передается в функцию?

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

почему переменная $city не передается в функцию, а $courses в where() подставляется.

```
public function search_course(Request $request)
    {
        $courses = $request->courses;
        $city = $request->city;

$paginator = Course::where('title', $courses)->whereHas('schools.cities', function (Builder $query) {

            $query->where('slug', $city);
        })->paginate(9);

   return view('courses');

    }
```

Comment: Используйте `function (Builder $query) use ($city) {`

Comment: спасибо большое